# Java/Jackson: Why serialized date has an extra 04?

Tags: java, serialization, time, jackson, jackson-databind

When I execute the following code:

```
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false).writeValueAsString(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("April 12, 2001")));
```

I see the output:

```
"2001-04-12T04:00:00.000+00:00"
```

I am trying to understand where the 04 after the T is coming from? My Jackson dependency:

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-databind", "2.11.1")
```

Comment: Are you - by any chance - in a UTC-4 timezone (e.g. EDT)?

Comment: Additional information: the representation `2001-04-12T04:00:00.000+00:00` is an [ISO 8601 date and time representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The last `+00:00` denotes the zone offset - in this case no offset, which is UTC. My assumption is that you are located in EDT, hence you have an offset of UTC -4, hence midnight at your timezone is 4 a.m. at UTC.

Comment: Date objects are always time stamps at a specific millisecond. That breaks down when you need actual calendar dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you're not specifying time and timezone, so output contains date-time in UTC timezone. Your system has timezone `UTC-4`, so, 4 hours are added to the date you've provided.

My timezone is `UTC+3`, so the output I'm getting

```
"2001-04-11T21:00:00.000+00:00"
```

I would recommend using Java 8 time for such cases, so you can always be sure what output you'll receive.

Following code outputs

```
"2001-04-12T00:00:00Z"
```

regardless your local timezone.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false).writeValueAsString(LocalDate.parse("April 12, 2001", formatter).atStartOfDay().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
```

P.S.
You can play around with parsed `LocalDate` and it's not necessary to convert it to `OffsetDateTime`